# Error 1004 select method of range class failed

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I can't see where I've gone wrong here, any help is appreciated.
I'm trying to cut and paste any rows that have the word 'solved' in them to another spreadsheet, but the code is getting stuck on cl.activate at the start of the loop.

```
    Sub FindString()
    Dim SearchString As String
    Dim SearchRange As Range, cl As Range
    Dim FirstFound As String
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    'Open first item to search and paste destination
    Workbooks.Open "G:\BS\Josh Whitfield\Credit_Chasing\NEW PROCESS\Markerstudy.xlsx"
    Workbooks.Open "G:\BS\Josh Whitfield\Credit_Chasing\NEW PROCESS\solved results.xlsx"
    Workbooks("markerstudy").Activate

    ' Set Search value
    SearchString = "solved"
    Application.FindFormat.Clear
    ' loop through all sheets
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ' Find first instance on sheet
        Set cl = sh.Cells.Find(What:=SearchString, _
            After:=sh.Cells(1, 1), _
            LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, _
            SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not cl Is Nothing Then
            ' if found, remember location
            FirstFound = cl.Address
            ' format found cell
            Do
                cl.Activate
                ActiveCell.EntireRow.Cut
                Workbooks("solved results").Activate
                Range("A1").Select
                If ActiveCell <> "" Then
                    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
                    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                Else
                    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                End If

                ' find next instance
                Set cl = sh.Cells.FindNext(After:=cl)
                ' repeat until back where we started
            Loop Until FirstFound = cl.Address
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to active the sheet first, with `cl.Parent.Activate`

```
    Sub FindString()
    Dim SearchString As String
    Dim SearchRange As Range, cl As Range
    Dim FirstFound As String
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    'Open first item to search and paste destination
    Workbooks.Open "G:\BS\Josh Whitfield\Credit_Chasing\NEW PROCESS\Markerstudy.xlsx"
    Workbooks.Open "G:\BS\Josh Whitfield\Credit_Chasing\NEW PROCESS\solved results.xlsx"
    Workbooks("markerstudy").Activate

    ' Set Search value
    SearchString = "solved"
    Application.FindFormat.Clear
    ' loop through all sheets
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ' Find first instance on sheet
        Set cl = sh.Cells.Find(What:=SearchString, _
            After:=sh.Cells(1, 1), _
            LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, _
            SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not cl Is Nothing Then
            ' if found, remember location
            FirstFound = cl.Address
            ' format found cell
            Do
                cl.Parent.Activate
                cl.Activate
                ActiveCell.EntireRow.Cut
                Workbooks("solved results").Activate
                Range("A1").Select
                If ActiveCell <> "" Then
                    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
                    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                Else
                    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                End If

                ' find next instance
                Set cl = sh.Cells.FindNext(After:=cl)
                ' repeat until back where we started
            Loop Until FirstFound = cl.Address
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Or just use `cl.EntireRow.Cut` and skip activating altogether. (otherwise you also need to activate the right workbook first)

Comment: @Rory : Indeed, I just stop at the activation issue and didn't read the next line...
But that is a better proposition if the OP doesn't need to use it (I do this to "debug" easily)

Comment: Thank you very much guys, both worked perfectly. Much appreciated.

Comment: @JoshWhitfield : Please take a minute to take the tour and learn how this site works (votes and accepting answers) : http://stackoverflow.com/tour